# Offset parametric curve

Tags: interpolation

I have a function ($a(x)=0.00005x^4-0.01x^3+0.68x^2-23.087x+322$) which defines a profile desired.

I need to get a new function that is shifted relative to the first function using a list (`offset=`${10,9.2,8.06,7.09,6.12,5.15,4.18,3.21,2.24,1.27,0.3}$) that determines points least for this new function.
This means that my new function should go in addition to these points and may not be below these values. Also should not allow the existence of any inflection point.

Through my code is possible to have na idea of what I need, but how can see, I couldn't avoid the inflection points and my function is not well as all least points.

Another issue: I this code `inters = Solve[a[x] == b, x]`, how so I use the value rational and positive? The code `inters = x /. inters[[4]]`, the value $4$ insert manually.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a[x_]:=0.00005x^4-0.01x^3+0.68x^2-23.087x+322;
ent=Range[0,20,2];
xinit=a[#]&/@ent//MatrixForm;
point1={ent[[#]],xinit[[1,#]]}&/@Range[Length[ent]];
offset={10,9.2,8.06,7.09,6.12,5.15,4.18,3.21,2.24,1.27,0.3};
newdata=ent[[#]]+offset[[#]]&/@Range[Length[ent]];
point2={newdata[[#]],xinit[[1,#]]}&/@Range[Length[ent]];
b=Fit[point2,{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4},x];
inters=Solve[a[x]==b,x]
inters=x/. inters[[4]];
Plot[{a[x],b},{x,0,60},PlotRange->{{0,inters},{0,point1[[1,2]]}},ImageSize->1100,AspectRatio->1,Epilog->{Red,PointSize[0.01],Point[{point1}],Point[{point2}],Black,Point[{x,b}/.Solve[D[b,{x,2}]==0]],Purple,Dashed,Line[{point1[[#]],point2[[#]]}]&/@Range[11]}]
```

[image]

Comment: In short: your offsets are horizontal offsets, as opposed to vertical or orthogonal offsets?

Comment: Yes. These are horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on comments:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

curve[x_] = 0.00005 x^4 - 0.01 x^3 + 0.68 x^2 - 23.087 x + 322;
offset = {10, 9.2, 8.06, 7.09, 6.12, 5.15, 4.18, 3.21, 2.24, 1.27, 0.3};

ent = Range[0, 20, 2];

curveList = Partition[Riffle[ent, curve[ent]], 2];
curveOffset = Partition[Riffle[ent + offset, curve[ent]], 2];

penalty[residuals_?VectorQ, scale_: 10] := 
  scale*Length@residuals*(1 - Sign@Min[residuals]);

scale = Max[curveOffset] - Min[curveOffset];
model = a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e;
fit = FindFit[curveOffset, model, {a, b, c, d, e}, x, 
   NormFunction -> (Norm[#1] + penalty[#1, scale] &), 
   Method -> "NMinimize", MaxIterations -> 10000];
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]

{tl, yl} = Transpose[curveOffset];
residuals = yl - Map[modelf, tl];
ListPlot[residuals, Filling -> Axis]

Show[
 ListPlot[{curveList, curveOffset}],
 Plot[modelf[x], {x, Min[ent + offset], Max[ent + offset]}]
 ]
```

Residuals plotted to show horizontal offset points are the minimum surface.

[image]

> 142.235 + 149.992 x - 22.4808 x^2 + 1.12361 x^3 - 0.0192096 x^4

Original and offset data overlaid with the above fit equation:

[image]

Reference: [How to fit a function to data so that the fit is always greater than or equal to the data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118843/how-to-fit-a-function-to-data-so-that-the-fit-is-always-greater-than-or-equal-to)

Comment: It is necessary that the curve is to the right of the minimum points. This list that I received define the lowest possible values ​​X may shift these values ​​to be larger so that there is inflection points

Comment: Sorry if the grammar is bad. English is not my native language.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho Let me know if the newly edited answer is what you wanted.

Comment: When I executed your code occured the following error: `The model ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e is linear in the parameters \ {a,b,c,d,e}, but a nonlinear method or non-Euclidean norm was \ specified, so nonlinear methods will be used`. Would be that´s right?

Comment: It's just a warning, but it's ok