# How to do deconvolution in spectrum with some peaks?

Tags: fitting, signal-processing

For example, I have the next spectrum:

[image]

I've seen the next question ["How to perform a multi-peak fitting?"][2]

but not answer to my question. I want deconvolution the spectrum to obtain three peaks (how Origin to do it). The sum of these three peaks gives the total spectrum. I know fit each peaks with gaussian or lorentziana function (or mixture of both) but this is different to deconvolution. My interest for deconvolution is find the FWHM each peak.

Are there codes for deconvolution data similar to mine?.

These are the datas of the spectrum: [Spectrum data](https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/Spectrum.txt/_518b3bdb5f87485d885dda9875448397)

[2]: [How to perform a multi-peak fitting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-)    multi-peak-fitting
This the code with the function for fitting each peak:

```
modelL = (2*A/Pi)*(w/(4*(x - xc)^2 + w^2));
modelGfh = A/(w*Sqrt[Pi/4 Log[2]])*E^(-4*Log[2]*(x - xc)^2/w^2);
r = 0.2;
modelLGfh = r*modelL + (1 - r)*modelGfh;
nlmD = NonlinearModelFit[peak1, 
modelLGfh, {{A, 1}, {w, 1}, {xc, 441}}, x, MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

Comment: What function are the peaks convolved with?

Comment: The spectrum is a list {x,y} of datas.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are asking can be answered by (1) finding local maximums and (2) using `NonlinearModelFit` for Gaussian functions that have those local maximums as peaks.

Comment: Is there actual data for this example?

Comment: @Manu Please see my preliminary answer. If it is close to what you want I can improve with more details and better fitting results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a complete answer. I want to hear from OP is this what he wants, then I can provide a full answer.

### Getting data

It would be good if data for the plot is provided in question. I extracted data points from the image attached to the question using the process described in the discussion ["Recovering data points from an image"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image).

[image]

### Finding local extrema

Using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95618/34008) I found the local extrema.

[image]

Here are the peaks:

```
In[136]:= peaks = extrema[[2, 1 ;; 3]] 
Out[136]= {{153, 580.}, {245, 527.}, {335, 498.}}
```

### Non-linear model fitting

For the three peaks we can generate three Gaussian functions and use Non-linear model fitting for their weighted sum.

Here are the functions:

```
In[196]:= fitFuncs = 
 Table[a[i] peaks[[i, 2]] PDF[NormalDistribution[peaks[[i, 1]], s[i]],
     x], {i, 3}]

Out[196]= {(231.387 E^(-((-153 + x)^2/(2 s[1]^2))) a[1])/s[1], (
 210.243 E^(-((-245 + x)^2/(2 s[2]^2))) a[2])/s[2], (
 198.673 E^(-((-335 + x)^2/(2 s[3]^2))) a[3])/s[3]}
```

Here is the fitting (with constraints):

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {Total[fitFuncs], {0 < a[1], 0 < a[2], 0 < a[3], 
    0 < s[1] < 20, 0 < s[2] < 30, 0 < s[3] < 150}}, 
  Join[Array[a, 3], Array[s, 3]], x]
```

Here are the found parameters:

```
In[226]:= nlm["BestFitParameters"]   
Out[226]= {a[1] -> 24.9994, a[2] -> 10.4565, a[3] -> 362.068, 
 s[1] -> 16.5082, s[2] -> 16.9777, s[3] -> 150.}
```

Plotting data and the fitted function:

[image]

### Quantile regression

Similar fitting for another MSE question, ["Fit a function to data so that fit is always equal or less than the data"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114864/fit-a-function-to-data-so-that-fit-is-always-equal-or-less-than-the-data), makes me think that with Quantile Regression we can get better results.

```
In[23]:= qfunc

Out[23]= 0. + 7.92161 E^(-0.005 (-335 + x)^2) + 
 50.8584 E^(-0.00125 (-335 + x)^2) + 
 53.4119 E^(-0.00005 (-335 + x)^2) + 
 381.914 E^(-0.0000125 (-335 + x)^2) + 
 9.10845 E^(-0.00138504 (-245 + x)^2) + 
 136.737 E^(-0.00131492 (-245 + x)^2) + 
 167.451 E^(-0.00274348 (-153 + x)^2) + 
 145.583 E^(-0.00255102 (-153 + x)^2)

In[22]:= Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[qfunc, {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank so much for your help. I've the similar result to your answer. My interest to deconvolution is find the FWHM each peak. I fitting each peak with a Gaussian plus Lorentziana function and then I can obtain the FWHM. I obtain this: ![Spectrum](http://thumbs.subefotos.com/8b84bde19d3e7afb9cc5ca356746493do.jpg)

Comment: @Manu Please list or specify with concrete formulas in your question what functions you want to fit. Also provide data.

Comment: Howerer, this is an approximation. For find the real FWHM of each peak is necessary deconvolution the spectrum.

Comment: I've edited the question. I provide the data and the function that I use for fit each peak.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think deconvolution is what you are really after. For example, there is a function called `ListDeconvolve`. Let's apply it to your data. First you need to specify a kernel for the deconvolution. Let's try a kernel that's a Gaussian of width 50:

```
gauss = GaussianMatrix[100][[50]];
ListPlot[ListDeconvolve[gauss, data], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now try a kernel of length 15:

```
gauss = GaussianMatrix[30][[15]];
ListPlot[ListDeconvolve[gauss, data2], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Neither is very satisfying because your peaks are of different widths. Deconvolution will only work if all three peaks are of roughly the same width (since you deconvolve the same kernel across the whole data set). So I think you are going to need to do something more like peak-picking as suggested by Anton.

Comment: Nice clarification. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I've analized the Anton Antonov solution with Non-linear model fitting:

```
peaks = Pick[sp[[630 ;; 880]], 
PeakDetect[sp[[630 ;; 880]][[All, 2]], 3.6, 0.05], 1]

fitFuncs = 
Table[a[i] peaks[[i, 2]] PDF[
NormalDistribution[peaks[[i, 1]], s[i]], x], {i, 3}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
sp, {Total[fitFuncs], {0 < a[1], 0 < a[2], 0 < a[3], 0 < s[1] < 20,
0 < s[2] < 30, 0 < s[3] < 150}}, Join[Array[a, 3], Array[s, 3]],
x];

nlm["BestFitParameters"];

a[1] = 7.377124955087864`; s[1] = 4.600197878756341`;
f1[x_] := fitFuncs[[1]];

a[2] = 3.840415143057309`; s[2] = 5.554311215744846`;
f2[x_] := fitFuncs[[2]];

a[3] = 107.9493889229601`; s[3] = 46.89436652386362`;
f3[x_] := fitFuncs[[3]];

Show[ListPlot[sp, PlotRange -> {{400, 700}, All}, Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}], 
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 400, 700}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}], 
Plot[f1[x], {x, 400, 600}, PlotStyle -> Brown, PlotRange -> All, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}], 
Plot[f2[x], {x, 400, 600}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}], 
Plot[f3[x], {x, 400, 600}, PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}]]
```

[image]

This results is very aproximated to deconvolution in Origin for example:

[image]

The results will improve using the Lorentziana plus Gaussiana function and/or Quantile regression that Anton Antonov indicated in his answer. just change the functions in the fitFuncs line.