# Making Quartile Plots from a dataset?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

Sometimes it is nice not just to show the median value of binned data, but also the quartiles thereof. However this doesn't seem to be so straightforward using `ListLinePlot`. What is a good approach to making binned, quartile, `ListLinePlots`?

Example below:
[image]

#### Update

Code available [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-Binned-Quartile-Plot/tree/master)

Comment: You can find the quartile curves using [Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/). See also the Quantile Regression posts in MSE [like this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137812/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov I have tried that with a list of tuples and didn't get any output....

Comment: Well it is not supposed to be used on lists of tuples, but lists of pairs, each pair seen as {time, value}.

Comment: @AntonAntonov my apologies for not clarifying, the tuples are effectively two values `{bin, value}`, so it should work....

Comment: Well, you have not provided data in both your question and your answer, so I cannot tell you what is wrong. Were you able to reproduce the QR computations in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137812/34008)? Both success and failure would give you hints why that QR package does not work for you.

Comment: @AntonAntonov the data can be simulated with `Partition[Riffle[RandomInteger[{10, 110}, 10000], RandomReal[{0, 2}, 10000]], {2}]`. Yes I used that post as my guide - although I modified it to remove the points since plotting `20,000` points clutters the plot. I think the error was that I remove the `PlotRange->All` along with the `Points`. How would one modify the code to just show the `CI`'s with the color scheme shown in my post?

Answer (score 6):

## Code

The code is publicly available [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-Binned-Quartile-Plot/tree/master).

---

I am answering my own question based off of something I worked out. I highly doubt that it is the best way to make quartile plots, but it works.

The code provided has a function that makes the `BinnedQuartilePlot` for either a `Dataset`, list of `Dataset`s (assumes you need the same keys for all of them), list of pairs, and list of lists of pairs. Two examples are below:

```
BinnedQuartilePlot[dataset, "keyToBin", "keyOfValues", "Bins" -> 15]
```

[image]

```
BinnedQuartilePlot[{dataset, dataset2}, "keyToBin", "keyOfValues",
                   "Bins" -> 15, "SwatchLegend" -> True, 
                   "Legends" -> {"Data1", "Data2"}]
```

[image]

I'll just go over the single `Dataset` case here.

## Single Dataset

Suppose you have a dataset, `data`, from which you care about two values, `x1` and `x2`.

Then we can extract the two values we care about by:

```
extractedPairs = Normal@data[All, {#x1, #x2}&];
```

Given the nature of `x1`, we want to bin `x1`. One way to bin the data (although one could extract this from the `Histogram` suite of functions) is as follows:

```
(* Set helper parameters *)
min = Min[First@First@SortBy[extractedPairs, First]];
max = Max[First@Last@SortBy[extractedPairs, First]];
bins = 10;
binStep = (max - min) / bins;

(* Bin values *)
Table[
  Cases[listOfPairs, 
    {x_ /; Round@((x - minBin)/binStep) == (bin - minBin)/binStep, y_} -> {bin, y}, 
    Infinity
  ], 
 {bin, minBin, maxBin, binStep}
]
```

Since we want the quartiles of the bins, we can just apply `Quartiles` and then `Transpose` the results to prepare them for `ListLinePlot`:

```
binnedQuartiles = Transpose /@ Quartiles /@ binnedValues;
```

This gives us our quartiles as paired triples e.g.

```
{{{bin1, q1}, {bin1, q2}, {bin1, q3}},
 {{bin2, q1}, {bin2, q2}, {bin2, q3}}, ...}
```

For list plot we need just the first pairs, second pairs, and the third pairs in their own respective lists, which we can make using:

```
listLineBinnedQuartiles = 
  Table[Flatten@Take[#, {i}] & /@ binnedQuartiles, {i, 1, 3}];
```

Thus finely we can make our quartile plot:

```
ListLinePlot[listLineBinnedQuartiles, 
 PlotStyle -> getNQuartileColors[1], Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.05]]
```

[image]

But all of this is encapsulated in `BinnedQuartilePlot` in the linked code.

## Multiple Datasets

This requires minor changes to the code to work on lists of `Dataset`s rather than just a single one. These changes are quite simple and easy to spot, e.g. to updated `extractedPairs`, it becomes

```
extractedPairs = Normal@#[All, #x1, #x2} &] & /@ listOfDatasets;
```

## Notes

There is (albeit poorly) simulated data with the linked code. Feel free to use your own.

There are a host of color functions as well. This is due mainly to needing to make custom `PlotStyle`s for the quartiles and then obtaining the same colors for the `SwatchLegend`.  If you don't like `"Pastel"` use the `Option` `"ColorScheme"` to change it to whatever you like.